# How to create multiple JSON files from Python

Tags: python, json

I need to create multiple JSON files from Python, for example:

```
[{
  'commentParentId': 'abcdedf',
  'parentId': '123456',
  'posted': '28/02/2019',
  'author': {
    'id': '125379',
    'name': 'david',
    'email': 'abc@gmail.com
   },
  'content': 'i need help'
  },
  {
  'commentParentId': 'abcdedf',
  'parentId': '253654',
  'posted': '28/02/2019',
  'author': {
    'id': '458216',
    'name': 'david',
    'email': 'abc@gmail.com
   },
  'content': 'i need help'
  },
  ........................
}]
```

The example: I have 10 comments with 10 id different and I want to create 10 JSON files with each. 1 JSON file has 1 JSON object and JSON name's author id.

But in Python, to write data in JSON file I use:

```
with open("scrapercomment.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as writeJSON:

    json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I don't have an idea of how to write 10 JSON files with each name is each id. I'm a newbie Python, JSON so thanks for your help.

Comment: So, how it's related to Selenium?

Comment: Before I asking, I think 2 ways to create multiple JSON files. 
First way: When I completed scraper 1 comment I will create JSON files. It means I don't add 10 comments in a list like my post.
Second way: I add 10 comments in a list and I write JSON files. 
I write: 'Scraper comments with Selenium ' because I want to everyone know my data not necessarily like my post. 
I will delete now, so thanks for your help to edit my post become clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `for` statement to iterate over comments and writing it a file.

```
for comment in comments:
    filename = f'/tmp/author_{comment["author"]["id"]}.json'
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as writeJSON:
        json.dump(comment, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: that amazing, i just think is a name of file, we cann't change automatic just can change when we input from keyboard. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```py
import json

with open('scrapercomment.json', 'r') as src:
    parsed_json = json.load(src)
    for comment in parsed_json:
        f = open(comment['author']['id'], 'w')
        f.write(str(comment))
        f.close()
```